# What is printf's "color 31" in Hexadecimal format?

Tags: colors, hex, printf

When I use printf's color functions to set a piece of text a particular numbers, like 31 for "red" What are their equivalents/conversions to hex?

Comment: what language is this?

Comment: This should help --> [Hex Color Picker](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_colorpicker.asp)